# QGIS print layout - map refresh not working

Tags: qgis, print-composer, printing

I would like to synchronize my QGIS map with the printing layout map.

According to the tutorial here:

https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/training_manual/map_composer/map_composer.html

I can refresh my map by clicking the "Refresh" symbol.
Unfortunately, despite the command "Refreshing map" appearing at the very bottom when clicking the icon, the map remains exactly the same as it was embedded initially.

[image]

Is it possible to sync the QGIS map canvas with the map provided in the print layout?

Comment: So you want to link scale AND position of your map item to the map canvas?

Comment: Yes, if it's possible

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before hitting refresh, you need to click the button to the right of it, which is "Set Map Extent to Match Main Canvas Extent".

This will set the zoom and extent of the map to match your main canvas.

Comment: Yes! Great! I don't even need to refresh it :)

Comment: Where is the button in QGIS 3.8 Firenze? In my view there is 'Lock selected item' to the right.

Comment: In the first picture of the original post, there are two arrows. Follow the one to the right of the image. The button is the one to the right of this refresh button.

Comment: Oh, yes, I found it. Thank you!