# QGIS Autosynchronizing of the main map canvas with 2 maps in the print composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer

My situation looks like this:

[image]

I would like to autosynchronize my QGIS map canvas  with 2 maps in the print composer, where one map is detailed and another map on the right is general including the yellow box for the 1st mmap borders. They should be draggable.
I found something nice here:

[Synchronizing views in QGIS print composer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250339/synchronizing-views-in-qgis-print-composer)

but the Python is required here.

The manual map refreshing:

[QGIS print layout - map refresh not working](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/393775/qgis-print-layout-map-refresh-not-working)

is not needed here, as it's simply not enough.

This video:

youtube.com/watch?v=8dF4ZLKBeEY&ab_channel=RoelVandePaar

shows 4 methods, but they didn't work really by far.

Is there any option to auto synchronize the three QGIS maps at once: Main map canvas, Map 1, and Map 2 in the printing layout?

Comment: Have you tried this (composer map overview) : https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/composer_items/composer_map.html#overviews ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is really simple for it.

We just should define the map frame for an overview, like shown below:

[image]

according to the following  tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rS40qG7m5zg&ab_channel=Geoinformatics

It's enough to keep this map updated against the main map in our print composer.

Next, if we want to sync this map with the QGIS map canvas, we must toggle the Main Map in our printing layout, where we should hit "Set Map Extent to Match Main Canvas Extent" as pointed in the answer below:

[QGIS print layout - map refresh not working](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/393775/qgis-print-layout-map-refresh-not-working)

[image]